# Проблема удаления репозитория на гите

Tags: git, github, repository

$ git push
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/account/repository.git/' not found

В чем проблема: Удалил репозиторий через сайт, теперь при пуше оно выдает ошибку. т.е. пушу в новый, а выдает ошибку, что отсутствует старый (ред)

пробовал разные способы, которые мне не помогли, может у Вас есть идеи

---

в скрытой папке .git > config

Есть такие строчки:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = https://github.com/account/repository.git/
    merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "remote"]
    url = https://github.com/account/repository.git/
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/remote/*
```

может тут можно что-то пофиксить?

Comment: __/.git/__ перед точкой отсутствует имя репозитория. Возможно сбились настройки адреса в вашем гите

Comment: Извините, при добавлении сообщения было затерта ссылка, я сдел правки

Comment: Эммм... вы удалили репозиторий, пушите в него, вам говорят, что его нет. Вопрос почему его нет или какой? можно удалить ветку и пушить в нее, она появится. А вот в отсутствующий репозиторий никак.

Comment: Я пушу в другой репозитарий

Comment: т.е. пушите в новый, а выдает ошибку, что отсутствует старый?

Comment: Да, все так и есть

Comment: @IRONteam что-то мне кажется, что вы пушите в старый, а не в новый. Магии не бывает.

Comment: Я работаю в рабочем репозитории, и ничего не изменяю. Просто нужно было сделать временно другой, и тут пришла эта проблема

Comment: Судя по фрагменту выложенного вами конфига - у вас настроен старый внешний репозиторий. Всего-то и нужно заменить его на новый...

Comment: Ок, а подскажите как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в папку и сделайте в консоли команду git remote -v и посмотрите что она выводит. Если в выводе нет нужного вам репозитория добавьте его как remote.

`$ git remote add remote https://github.com/account/repository.git/`

и проверьте какое состояние подключенных репозиториев примерно так должно быть:

`$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/account/repository.git/ (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/account/repository.git/ (push)
remote  https://github.com/account/repository.git/ (fetch)
remote  https://github.com/account/repository.git/ (push)`

Comment: Сделал сначала  $ git remote add remote https://github.com/account/repository.git/;
потом 
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/account/repository.git/ (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/account/repository.git/ (push)
Далее когда пушу 
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/account/repository.git/' not found